# Spring-data-redis Jedis RedisMessageListenerContainer -Connection failure occurred. Restarting subscription task after 5000 ms

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis, jedis

I found some similar problems here but the solutions does not fix mine, there seems to be a mistake in my message listener (subscription) configuration.

I am pretty new with redis and I would like to lister/read/subscribe to an existing redis server which does not have any password.

I can listen to that server via redis-cli on my local, but when I try to add a redis listener to my spring boot app, it seems the message listener container cannot establish a connection.

I am getting this repeating message:

`2021-01-18 22:12:32 [redisContainer-31] ERROR o.s.d.r.l.RedisMessageListenerContainer -Connection failure occurred. Restarting subscription task after 5000 ms`

Below are some of the snippets on how I add `spring-data-redis (2.3.3.RELEASE)` + `jedis (2.10.0)` spring boot to my application.

**pom.xml**

```
  ...
  <properties>
    ...
    <redis.version>2.3.3.RELEASE</redis.version>
    <jedis.version>2.10.0</jedis.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    ...  
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
      <version>${redis.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- There is no redis.clients.util.SafeEncoder class definition in version 3.1.0 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
      <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
      <version>${jedis.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  ...
```

**application.properties**

```
# Redis
spring.redis.database=0
spring.redis.host=sabong-dev.abs3252.8888.use69.cache.amazonaws.com
spring.redis.port=6379
spring.redis.password=
spring.redis.timeout=60000
spring.redis.channel.sabongEvents=SABONG_EVENTS
```

please note that there is no password for connecting to the existing redis server, and I can read/listener to `SABONG_EVENTS` locally using `redis-cli`.

**RedisConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
public class RedisConfig {

    @Value("${spring.redis.host}")
    private String redisHost;

    @Value("${spring.redis.port}")
    private Integer redisPort;

    @Value("${spring.redis.channel.sabongEvents}")
    private String channelTopic;

    @Bean
    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(redisHost, redisPort);
        return new JedisConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration);
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    MessageListenerAdapter messageListener() {
        return new MessageListenerAdapter(new MyRedisMessageSubscriber());
    }

    @Bean
    RedisMessageListenerContainer redisContainer() {
        RedisMessageListenerContainer container = new RedisMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
        container.addMessageListener(messageListener(), channelTopic());
        return container;
    }

    @Bean
    ChannelTopic channelTopic() {
        return new ChannelTopic(channelTopic);
    }

}
```

**MyRedisMessageSubscriber.java**

```
package package.my.sample;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.Message;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.MessageListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

...

@Service
public class RedisMessageSubscriber implements MessageListener {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyRedisMessageSubscriber.class);

    public void onMessage(Message message, byte[] pattern) {
        String msg = message.toString();
        logger.info("\n[topic-message]: {}\n", msg);
    }

}
```

I am not sure what is wrong with my codes, I know this is very simple since I just want to display sysout/logger.info the messages I get from redis channel.

The application runs but it cannot establish a connection inorder to make read/listen.

I may be missing some codes or configuration here but I am not sure where or what.

Thanks!

**Update (Solution)**
It seems spring-boot did not automagically set my redis host and port, maybe because I missed something or some wrong property names causing it not set automatically.

In my redis configuration class, I set the redis host and port in my `JedisConnectionFactory` using `RedisStandaloneConfiguration`. Since my problem is just establishing the connection to my message listener container.. it was able to make a connection to my external redis server with this sample.

Instead of removing this post, I just updated it with answer cause I know I might be needing this again since I am very forgetful :)

Answer (score 0):

After debugging, I found out that my configuration properties seems not to work

```
spring.redis.host=sabong-dev.abs3252.8888.use69.cache.amazonaws.com
spring.redis.port=6379
```

I was expecting that spring boot will set these properties values for me.
As I debugged, the `JedisConnectionFactory` is still pointing to `localhost` and `6379`. No problem with the port since it is the same value as what I am expecting, but `localhost` seems to be the default value not the one I set or expected.

So inorder to set the host/port since `JedisConnectionFactory.setHost(host)` and `JedisConnectionFactory.setPort(port)` are deprecated, I use `RedisStandaloneConfiguration` to set both host and port and use this in the constructor of `JedisConnectionFactory`. So it will look like this.

**RedisConfig.java**

```
...
@Value("${spring.redis.host}")
private String redisHost;

@Value("${spring.redis.port}")
private Integer redisPort;

@Value("${spring.redis.channel.sabongEvents}")
private String channelTopic;
...

@Bean
JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
    RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(redisHost, redisPort);
    return new JedisConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration);
}
```

After setting the correct host (and port), it was able to establish a connection to my redis server and channel.

Again, my issue is my  message listener container is having a connection problem and the main problem was... my redis host and port was not set automatically by spring-boot. I know there might be some mistakes to my properties causing spring-boot not to set it properly. But the idea is, once I set both redis host and port, I was able to connect to my server, and I was able to read/listen to my set channel.

I will update my original post and fix the code